# Add tooltip for Mui Datatables filter

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I want to change the filter icon tooltip for a mui datatable in my project. Currently it is coming up as 'Filter Table' and I want to change this to 'Filter' only:
[Filter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUXiS.jpg)

I tried doing this by adding, but this didnt work for me:

```js
const options = {{
  textLabels: {
    body: {
      toolTip: "Filter",
    },
    filter: {
      title: "FILTERS",
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mui-datatables`'s `components` prop to create custom `Tooltip`

```
<MUIDataTable
   data={data}
   columns={columns}
   components={{
      Tooltip: CustomTooltip
   }}
/>

const CustomTooltip = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return (
      <MuiTooltip
        {...props}
        title={props.title === "Filter Table" ? "Filter" : props.title}
      >
        {children}
      </MuiTooltip>
    );
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-forked-z6ddl0